# Find the discriminant and comment on the discriminant.

Tags: polynomials

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be non zero real numbers and $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ be real numbers.Find the discriminant of the quadratic equation

> $$(a_{1}x-b_1)^2+(a_{2}x-b_2)^2+(a_{3}x-b_3)^2+\dots+(a_{n}x-b_n)^2=0$$.

Whats can you say about the discriminant?

My attempt:

$(a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+\dots+a_{n}^2)x^2-2x(a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+\dots+a_{n}b_{n})+(b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2+\dots+b_{n}^2)$

$Discriminant=4(a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+\dots+a_{n}b_{n})^2-4((b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2+\dots+b_{n}^2)(a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2+\dots+a_{n}^2)$

How to proceed further?

Comment: Try what happens when $n=2,3,\ldots$. I'm fairly sure you will see a pattern. Testing small values of the parameter is often useful (and IMHO should be in the toolbag of people interested in contest math as well as all math majors). I suspect that an answer in terms of [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Elementary_symmetric_polynomials) is expected.

Comment: Use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Comment: How many real roots does the quadratic in $x$ have? How does that relate to the discriminant?

Comment: @gammatester This is a proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.